# What are the names these riddles point to?

Tags: riddle

I'm playing an interactive text game and I'm stumped by the following riddles (the answers are names per the game context):

1. A villain with a common heart. Ten is his end, but he's fifty to start.

and

2. Cut off her head, she's male. Cut off her tail, she's a fruit. Cut off both, she's part of you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Lex.  (L is 50 in Roman numerals, X is 10, E is a common letter, Lex Luthor is a well-known "villain".)
2. Pearl.  ("Earl" is male, "Pear" is a fruit, "Ear" is a part of you.)

Comment: Amusingly, I was on the same track for #2 but completely forgot about Earl as a name until I saw you capitalize it. I was thinking of the peerage title.

Answer (score 2):

1. is a pack of cards. There are four jacks or 'knaves', a knave is a villain. Hearts make up a quarter of the pack, that's pretty common. 'Ten' is the highest or 'end' numeral and you start with 'fifty-two (to)' of them.
   SO if you're looking for a name, I suppose it would be 'Jack'.

Comment: Nice alternative solution!